# jQuery Toggle between tab images

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with a simple toggle. Well, it should be simple. I'm visiting forums and threads and can't quite get it to work.

I have three tab images (not part of any package) and I simply want the clicked image to switch to "on" and others to switch to "off"

```
<img class="mastheadTab" id="products" src="#application.viewImageDIR#/tab_products_on.gif" width="119" height="31" hspace="4">

<img class="mastheadTab" id="suppliers" src="#application.viewImageDIR#/tab_suppliers_off.gif" width="117" height="31" hspace="4">

<img class="mastheadTab" id="buyers" src="#application.viewImageDIR#/tab_buyers_off.gif" width="117" height="31" hspace="4">
```

Here is my slack Jquery, which is in need of fixing.
Somehow, I need to reinitialise the tabs, because the clicks are crossing over each other and displaying the wrong image in the wrong position and not switching states till after the second or third click.

```
$(".mastheadTab").live("click", function(e) {
 var tab = $(this).attr("id")

 $('.mastheadTab').toggle(
  function(){$(this).attr("src", "/chinabuy-new/images/website/tab_" + tab + "_on.gif"); },
  function(){$(this).attr("src", "/chinabuy-new/images/website/tab_" + tab + "_off.gif"); }
 );
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `id` at the time of the click, like this:

```
$(".mastheadTab").click(function(){
  //turn the others off
  $(".mastheadTab").not(this).attr("src", function(i, src) {
    return src.replace("_on", "_off");
  });
  //toggle this image's source
  this.src = this.src.replace(/(_off|_on)/, function(i, m) {
    return m == "_off" ? "_on" : "_off";
  });
});
```

Currently you're getting the `id` for the clicked image and attaching a *new* toggle set of `click` handlers each time.  Instead just use the code above to get th `id` for the image you clicked on.

Comment: Thanks Nick, That stops the crossover. Two issues remain:
1) It takes two clicks for the tab to change on first load
2) I need to switch off other tabs that were on

Comment: @Paul - try the updated answer, it should address both issues.

Comment: Nick, thanks, but it's still doing odd things. Here is a link so you can see what's happening: 
http://www.china-buy.com/chinabuy-new/index.cfm

Comment: @Paul - this shouldn't be inside your `.live()` handler...it should replace all the code in the question.

Comment: Ooops. That was dumb. It's working Nick. God bless you. Hope they're paying you well where you're at. You deserve it.